# ActiveRecord Joins is not fetching data from multiple table. It is working for manual execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am building a RestAPI using Rails 5. I have 3 tables currently

- Members
- ContactSource (name)
- ContactSourceMemberMap (member_id, contact_source_id, value)

Where,

```
class ContactSourceMemberMap < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :member
    belongs_to :contact_source
end
```

Now I want to fetch **name from ContactSource** and **value from ContactSourceMemberMap**.

I tried:

`ContactSource.eager_load(:contact_source_member_maps).select("contact_sources.name", "contact_source_member_maps.value")`

on ContactSourceMemberMap model.

The SQL which is getting generating is fetching data by performing INNER JOIN. But on the rails end its coming like

```
[#<ContactSource:0x007fa14f261950
 id: 1,
 name: "ContactSource1",
 created_at: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 16:33:00 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 16:33:00 UTC +00:00>,
#<ContactSource:0x007fa14f200290
 id: 2,
 name: "ContactSource2",
 created_at: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 16:33:00 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 16:33:00 UTC +00:00>,
#<ContactSource:0x007fa14fa8fb18
 id: 3,
 name: "ContactSource3",
 created_at: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 16:33:00 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 16:33:00 UTC +00:00>,
#<ContactSource:0x007fa14fa8f2d0
 id: 4,
 name: "ContactSource4",
 created_at: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 16:33:00 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 16:33:00 UTC +00:00>]}]
```

It is not displaying the value field. Any thoughts why is it behaving like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
contact_sources = ContactSource.eager_load(:contact_source_member_maps).select("contact_sources.name", "contact_source_member_maps.value")
```

and then you can get the other object with

```
contact_sources.first.contact_source_member_maps
```

if I am wrong you can check the [following guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)